# Play tags$audio file until the end in Shiny App R

Tags: html, r, audio, shiny

I have a shiny app that is kind of like a Piano keyboard. I press a button and it plays a sound. It looks something like this:

if (input$down[1] == 65){
tags$audio(src = "Low_C.wav", type = "audio/wav", autoplay = NA, controls = FALSE)}
else if(input$down[1] == 87){
tags$audio(src = "Low_C_Sharp.wav", type = "audio/wav", autoplay = NA, controls = NA)}

Every time I press 65 (letter a on my keyboard), it plays low c. But when I press 87 (letter w) it stops playing low c and plays low c sharp.

I want to be able to press 65, it play low c until the end of "Low_C.wav" even if I press 87 before then end, it should play them together.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I figured it out and thought I'd share.

Instead of tags$audio, I used

tags$script('new Audio ("Low_C.wav").play()')

and

tags$script('new Audio ("Low_C_Sharp.wav").play()')

It can play multiple sounds at once this way.